# Incorrect path to public folder

Tags: laravel-5

In laravel i given a link that searches the given file in public folder.
Here is the code,

```
<tr>
<span class="label label-success">
<a href='home.blade.php'>Edit</a>
</span>
<br>
<tr>
```

But my file is in resources/views,how should i change my code

Comment: that's not right way for making link , you should make a route and on that route make that blade file

Answer (score 0):

that's not right way for making link , you should make a route and on that route make that blade file 
some thing like this

```
<a href="{!! route('user_get') !!}">
```

hope this will help you